# Moving function around without cut and pate?

Tags: ide, notepad++

I want to know if there is any IDE can moving function around in drag and drop without cute and paste?

I'm current using Notepad++, maybe there is any tip for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Notepad++ once you have selected the function you want to move you can drag (move) it in two ways:

1. *with your mouse* keeping left mouse button down while dragging
2. *with your keyboard* using <kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd>  while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> to move the entire selection up or down